# How to loop through two elements simultaneously?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I want to loop through two lists at the same time using a for loop in python because I will be comparing their contents using `filecmp` and skipping on to the next iteration if file content is the same. So I'd like both to start from index 0, does this work syntax work and what is the best way to do so?

```
file_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "../pythonProject", "*.json"))
duplicated_File_List = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "../pythonProject/executed_Configs", "*.json"))

 for file_Path, test in file_list, duplicated_File_List:
    with open(file_Path) as jsonfile:            
        monitor_Data = json.load(jsonfile)
        logging.info("Read successful")
        while i < length:
            if filecmp.cmp(file_Path, test, shallow=True):
                i += 1
            continue
```

where `file_Path` is the individual file element in `file_list` and `test` is the individual element in `duplicated_File_List`.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are showing us in the for loop is iterables with the same length you can do this to loop:

```
 for file_Path, test in zip(file_list, duplicated_File_List):
      # rest of your code ...
```

I still did not understand what is the propose of your inner while loop...

Comment: Would zipping the files not hold the contents of each list as a single unit?

Comment: How many time do you intend the loop to run? I think its not enough clear.. with zip you would iterate it only once assuming two lists are same length...

Comment: oh okay, I just didn't understand how the zip functionality worked. I was thinking it would store both files into one single file when zip is used.